# Updating the Values of Multiple Instances of a React Component Returns .map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a webpage that is made up of a component containing a dropdown menu of restrictions, and textbox for integer entry. However, since the component can be cloned I am using the map function to make copies. When I go to update the value of either the textbox or the dropdown, the console returns `TypeError: this.state.selectedIntervals.map is not a function`.

My code is separated into a parent(App.js) and child component(Intervals.js). Intervals.js contains event handlers to check for values being updated and App.js makes copies of the Intervals component with the map function.

From previous posts, I have tried to check whether updating the value removes elements from my array and modifying the method through how events are handled in the child component with no luck.

The following is a reduced version of the code. Ignore the `countries` and `selectedCountry` parts of the state, they are for another purpose.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
///import NavigationMenu from "../NavigationMenu";
import Intervals from "../Components/Intervals";

class Application extends Component {
  state = {
    countries: [
      { id: 1, country: "USA" },
      { id: 2, country: "Brazil" },
      { id: 3, country: "Russia" },
    ],
    selectedCountry: [{ value: 0 }],
    selectedIntervals: [{ id: 1, duration: 0, restriction: "None" }],
  };

  handleInterval = (newValue) => {
    this.setState({ selectedIntervals: { duration: newValue } });
  };

  handleNewInterval = () => {
    const selectedIntervals = [...this.state.selectedIntervals];
    selectedIntervals.push({
      id: this.state.selectedIntervals.length + 1,
      duration: 0,
      restriction: "None",
    });
    this.setState({ selectedIntervals });
  };

  handleDeleteInterval = () => {
    const selectedIntervals = [...this.state.selectedIntervals];
    selectedIntervals.pop();
    this.setState({ selectedIntervals });
  };

  handleRestriction = (newValue) => {
    this.setState({ selectedIntervals: { restriction: newValue } });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.handleNewInterval}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleDeleteInterval}>-</button>
        <br />
        <div>
          {this.state.selectedIntervals.map((interval) => (
            <Intervals
              key={interval.id}
              duration={interval.duration}
              restriction={interval.restriction}
              onIntervalUpdate={this.handleInterval}
              onRestrictionUpdate={this.handleRestriction}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Application;
```

Intervals.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Intervals extends Component {
  handleRestrictionChange = (event) => {
    this.props.onRestrictionUpdate(event.target.value);
  };
  handleDurationChange = (event) => {
    this.props.onIntervalUpdate(event.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          Enter the length of the interval:&nbsp;
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleDurationChange} />
          <select onChange={this.handleRestrictionChange} defaultValue="None">
            <option key="1" value="Lockdown">
              Lockdown
            </option>
            <option key="2" value="Vacation">
              Vacation
            </option>
            <option key="3" value="School closure">
              School closure
            </option>
            <option key="4" value="None">
              None
            </option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Intervals;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
handleInterval = (newValue) => {
    this.setState({ selectedIntervals: { duration: newValue } });
};
```

You forgot to wrap it in an array:

```js
handleInterval = (newValue) => {
    this.setState({ selectedIntervals: [{ duration: newValue }] });
};
```

EDIT: looks like you're trying to do a deep merge. `setState` won't merge only on the top level. Deep objects need to be merged manually.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. It works!